# Google Places API timeout through proxy

Tags: javascript, google-maps, graphql, google-places-api, apollo

I am building a React/graphQL/redux project with a map section. The Google Map works fine, but I want to implement a Searchbar and the graphql query is receiving a timeout ONLY if I am using my company's proxy. 
the URL works fine on the browser

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=farmacia+barcelona&key=key

Any help is appreciated.

```
const MAP_SEARCH_QUERY = gql`
  query mapSearchQuery($search:GoogleMapsSearchInput) {
    googleMapsTextSearch(search:$search) {
      id
      name
      geometry {
        location {
          lat
          lng
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
const search = { searchStrings: ['whatever I'm searching'] };
const result = await apolloClient.query({
          query: MAP_SEARCH_QUERY,
          variables: { search }
        });
```

IT is weird because it works if I'm fetching data from the CMS but not to Google Places API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that proxies can mangle requests and break them, so you may need to debug your proxy first.

Furthermore, make sure that the API key you're using to call Google's Places API has whitelisted the proxy's IP address in its [application restrictions](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key#restrict_key).

Finally, check that your firewall isn't blocking these requests. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58746596/11742502).

Hope this helps!